# arp -a returns only one device on Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, kali-linux, internet, arp

I'm running a Kali Linux live USB. I recently was unable to connect to my Wi-Fi network, but I found a Wi-Fi adapter that let me connect to my network and use the internet without experiencing any issues. However, when I open my terminal and run `arp -a`, I only see one device with the IP address `192.168.86.1`. I don't know if this is the USB's "IP address" or if it belongs to the adapter or the router, but I am unable to see any other devices connected to my network even though I know that there are.

Answer (score 0):

The *cache is fresh* on your device.

### explanation

---

Live boot images are non persistent cached (non cache slinging cache-er) To avoid this problem in the future setup  an usb image that has file persistence.

**Your fix** will have to be done every time, or run some kind of network discover protocol at boot to discover addresses....

That being said it has only talked to your router and modem. It needs to be updated, ARP reads from cache....

---

### TLDR

#### run this to reset the cache for the ip protocol:

```
    ip link set arp off dev eth0 ; ip link set arp on dev eth0
```

When your done with that, run this copypasta to resolve the interfaces as well...

```
    interfaces=$(
      arp -n | awk '
        NR == 1 {next}
        {interfaces[$5]+=1}
        END {for (interface in interfaces){print(interface)}}
      '
    );
    for interface in $interfaces; do
      echo "Clearing ARP cache for $interface";
      sudo ip link set arp off dev $interface;
      sudo ip link set arp on  dev $interface;
    done
```

### TLDR #2

Your writing cache (oxymoron i know) could be disabled on the usb if you did not allow for persistence.

#### Write Caching in Linux

Press CTRL+ALT+T to launch the Terminal.

```
    Run sudo gedit /etc/hdparm.conf
```

Find write_cache and remove the # in front of it.
Save and restart the computer.

---

This next step is

*** only for the desperate ***

```
FROM ARP MAN PAGE



-D, --use-device
              Instead of a hw_addr, the given argument is the name of an
              interface.  arp will use the MAC address of that interface
              for the table entry. This is usually the best option to
              set up a proxy ARP entry to yourself.

      -i If, --device If
              Select an interface. When dumping the ARP cache only
              entries matching the specified interface will be printed.
              When setting a permanent or temp ARP entry this interface
              will be associated with the entry; if this option is not
              used, the kernel will guess based on the routing table.
              For pub entries the specified interface is the interface
              on which ARP requests will be answered.
              NOTE: This has to be different from the interface to which
              the IP datagrams will be routed.  NOTE: As of kernel 2.2.0
              it is no longer possible to set an ARP entry for an entire
              subnet. Linux instead does automagic proxy arp when a
              route exists and it is forwarding. See arp(7) for details.
              Also the dontpub option which is available for delete and
              set operations cannot be used with 2.4 and newer kernels.
```

ARP reads entries from cache. try updating your cache or creating a live image that apoints to another (see above)